# Apache Beam WriteToText on a local path FileNotFound

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to run an Apache Beam job via a Spark Job that runs via Docker.

Here's the pipeline:

```py
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(["--runner=PortableRunner",
                                    "--job_endpoint=localhost:8099"],
                                   pipeline_type_check=True)
input = 'kinglear.txt'

# with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_type_check=True)) as p:
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    # Read the text file[pattern] into a PCollection.
    def output(x):
        print(str(x))
        return x


    lines = (p
             | beam.io.ReadFromText(input))

    # Count the occurrences of each word.
    counts = (
            lines
            | 'Split' >> (beam.FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\']+', x))
                          .with_output_types(unicode))
            | 'PairWithOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
            | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
            | 'WriteToText' >> WriteToText(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '/output/part')))
```

The pipeline runs fine, until the last step, where I get the following:

```
RuntimeError: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/output/beam-temp-part-5039fdd2d6c511e9b2ed2c4d54e984b7/a0ac2e38-dd8d-4748-8700-f1a114de0e1d.part.gz' [while running 'WriteToText/Write/WriteImpl/FinalizeWrite']
```

How should I specify the output path?